# Python Map symbol to data based on position in list

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a list that I utilize in a loop that inputs the stock symbols into an API, however the  output from the API does not include the symbol/ticker.  I want to leverage the order of the list to map the symbol/ticker to the dataframe output(i transfer from the API) which is in sequential chronological order, which repeats for each ticker.  Meaning, that the function would start to fill down the ticker based on the list order for each unique DateTime and once it realizes that it is starting over at 9:00 again, it would move on to the next symbol.  I am not sure if this can be done, but i am open to suggestions.

```
symbols =['MSFT', 'GOOG', 'AAPL']

Output:
DateTime    Price    Volume    Symbol(i want to add the symbol)
9:00        212.50   100       currently blank (mapping would add 'MSFT'
9:10        212.75   200       currently blank (mapping would add 'MSFT'
9:20        212.65   500       currently blank (mapping would add 'MSFT' 
9:00        1010.50  100       currently blank (mapping would add 'GOOG'
9:10        1012.65  200       currently blank (mapping would add 'GOOG'
9:20        1011.05  500       currently blank (mapping would add 'GOOG' 
9:00        128.05   100       currently blank (mapping would add 'AAPL'
9:10        128.65   200       currently blank (mapping would add 'AAPL'
9:20        129.10   500       currently blank (mapping would add 'AAPL'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
for i, item in enumerate(output_list):
    item['Symbol'] = symbols[i % len(symbols)]
```

Comment: thanks for your help!  I think we are on the right track, but this applied 'GOOG' to the entire dataset?  in order to apply, i used the following: for i, item in enumerate(df1):
    df1['Symbol'] = symbols[i % len(symbols)] does this look correct?

Comment: That would change the whole list. What I wrote works for me, can you share the exact code snippet you are trying to run?